# Database HANA Error : cannot use parameter variable

Tags: sql, hana

I'm trying to insert value into my temporary table with the code below.

And I got this error

> SAP Hana Database Error: cannot
> use parameter variable: DOCENTRY: line 8 col 35 (at pos 127)  2   0

I don't know what is wrong,
Please give some advise
thanks

This is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE REP_PROC11( in docentry nvarchar(2))
AS 

totalval DECIMAL (19,6);


BEGIN
CREATE local TEMPORARY  TABLE #TempItem AS (
select
'FGA000001' as "ItemCode",
'2IN' as "WhsCode",
ifnull(
(
    select 
        "U_IM1_GR"
    from "@OFNC" where "DocEntry"  = :docentry
),0) as "Qty",
'11080302' as "Account",
'S02' as "ProfitCode",
'IN-PN' as "ProfitCode2" 
from DUMMY

union all

select
'FGA000002' as "ItemCode",
'2IN' as "WhsCode",
ifnull(
(
    select 
        U_IM2_GR 
    from "@OFNC" where "DocEntry"  = :docentry
),0) as "Qty",
'11080302' as "Account",
'S02' as "ProfitCode",
'IN-FN' as "ProfitCode2" from dummy);

SELECT X.*, (X."Qty"*:totalval)/Y."TotalQty" as "Val", :totalval as "TotalVal"
FROM #TempItem X
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(X1."Qty") as "TotalQty" FROM #TempItem X1) Y ON 1 = 1
WHERE X."Qty" > 0;

drop TABLE #TempItem;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s a limitation of the SQL in your DDL code - the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` bit.

Given your code so far, you don’t need to use a temp. table but could yield the same result (with less resource usage) by using table variables.

Comment: Sorry I have solved the problem by declaring the table structure and then do some insert. 
For now I just want some answer, why I got that error. thanks

Comment: As I wrote: that’s a limitation of dynamic sq within SQLScript. There’s really no need for a temp table though in this scenario.